# Can windows 8/8.1 app be started at startup

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows

I need to know can a windows 8/8.1 app be opened during startup on both phone as well as desktop/laptop. If yes please help me how to make it run on startup.Because i wanna develop a universal app for the store. Please help me with this concept. Thank You

Comment: I actually found a simpler way to start an app at startup,. Its to use cmd "Start <APPNAME>: " in a batch file and put it onto the startup folder...
Who ever tried to solve this thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IApplicationActivationManager::ActivateApplication` method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706903(v=vs.85).aspx

There is an example here: https://github.com/krkarnat/SmartApp/blob/fde7ee082de501b4c80d08bc090d489cdf7c1da7/phonegap-2.9.1/lib/windows/windows8/tooling/CordovaWindows8Deploy/CordovaWindows8Deploy.cpp